# How to Tune the Java GC for vanilla benchmarks?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, benchmarking

I'm trying to tune the GC such that it won't kick in during a short benchmark.

For that I tried to set the young generation as big as I can and made sure I create less garbage than the Eden size.

I used the following parameters:

```
java -Xmx1g -Xms1g -Xmn1g -XX:NewSize=1000m -XX:MaxNewSize=1g -XX:SurvivorRatio=10000 -verbose:gc Main
```

But for some reason I still see [Full GC] logs when the VM memory is only at 300M, is there any JVM tuning I'm missing?

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing your code. Perhaps you could come up with a short runnable example that (unexpectedly) exhibits this behaviour, and post it here? This would enable us to experiment with it, and understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to create one. Does it mean that in general you think I can achieve the expected goal?

Comment: In principle, yes (provided your code doesn't produce enough garbage to require collection).

Comment: As I wrote in the question I see the full GC kicks in at 300M while I have 1G.

Comment: These are the GC logs we see:

[Full GC 444212K->53612K(1048512K), 0.1674871 secs]
[Full GC 98878K->53600K(1048512K), 0.1353826 secs]
[Full GC 117736K->53600K(1048512K), 0.1126983 secs]
[Full GC 96769K->53600K(1048512K), 0.1046997 secs]
[Full GC 202470K->53600K(1048512K), 0.1597075 secs]
[Full GC 56930K->53600K(1048512K), 0.1134397 secs]
[Full GC 267471K->53756K(1048512K), 0.1372057 secs]
[Full GC 54990K->53756K(1048512K), 0.1068497 secs]
[Full GC 160691K->53912K(1048512K), 0.1366148 secs]
[Full GC 122243K->53913K(1048512K), 0.1218144 secs]
[Full GC 360042K->53922K(1048512K), 0.1614036 secs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GC is still going to run if you're deallocating lot's of objects, it's not purely a matter of waiting until you have used all of the allocated space, if it did that it would lead to serious GC jitter on occasions when it did run.

You should be looking at your use of object handling and whether you could be more efficient. Take a look at the LMAX disrupter pattern for some ideas on how to use objects for reuse, by updating the object values, rather than deallocating an replacing the objects themselves.

That being said, this is a pretty good article on tuning the GC - http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/4EasyWaystodoJavaGarbageCollectionTuning.aspx

Comment: I know, but I don't really want to run with these parameters in production, but to isolate the GC pauses from the application logic.

Comment: In which case all the more reason to look at how you're handling objects. If you have large deallocation, you're going to have high GC. How are objects referenced in your application? Are you creating processing classes each time they're required rather than reusing them? If the issue is that you have a lot of new data coming into the application that you only need for a short period of time look to create a set of objects you never deallocate but use to hold the primitive values that come into the application and continually reuse them.

Comment: You should leave the GC on with its application settings, and just average the runtime as usual -- that'll take into account the average GC load created by the code being benchmarked.

Comment: We do that in our benchmarks and for sure this is the only real way to measure things. And yet, to my question, do you know a way to set the GC in such way?

Answer (score 2):

Your survivor ration is very important, with 10 000 you are telling the JVM that a survivor space is one 10000th the size of eden.

[From documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) :

> If survivor spaces are too small, copying collection overflows directly into the tenured generation. If survivor spaces are too large, they will be uselessly empty. At each garbage collection the virtual machine chooses a threshold number of times an object can be copied before it is tenured. This threshold is chosen to keep the survivors half full. The command-line option -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution can be used to show this threshold and the ages of objects in the new generation. It is also useful for observing the lifetime distribution of an application.

So obviously with a so low survivor space ratio, your objects are directly stored in the tenured generation.

When the tenured generation is full a **major collection** happened and that's why you see `[Full GC...]` in the log.

If you want to make the young generation bigger use :

```
-XX:NewRatio=1
```

It means the combined size of the eden and survivor spaces will be one half of the total heap size. (I guess you can't have a bigger young generation)

Also you don't have to set `-XX:NewSize` if you have already set `-Xmn`, `-Xmn` is the same thing since 1.4. And I guess you don't want to bound young gen from above with `-XX:MaxNewSize`, the default value is unlimited. But setting the size of the young generation with the same value as the max heap size imply you don't let space for old generation so I guess the JVM will resize generations.

To conclude there is also some case where allocations can occur directly into the tenured generation. ([Do objects ever get allocated directly into the old generation?](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html))

> - If an allocation fails in the young generation and the object is a large array that does not contain any references to objects, it can be allocated directly into the old generation. In some select instances, this strategy was intended to avoid a collection of the young generation by allocating from the old generation.
>     The threshold size is 64k words.

Comment: My hope was that since the Eden is so big will never get collected. Therefor the GC will never try to put objects in the survival area.

Comment: @GuyKorland I've made an edit. I hope those informations will be helpfull ;)

Comment: Thanks for the last edition, is there a way to control the "The threshold size is 64k words."?

Comment: Actually the 64k size depends on your JVM version and the collector you use. if you read the full answer given in the second link, you will see that this treshold has been raised to the size of the young gen, and the option that can set the treshold is already set to unlimited by default. So I guess you couldn't do anything for that. Just give your young generation a correct size, avoid to exceed half the heap size.

Answer (score 2):

You can get full GC because your tenured space has filled up (large objects are placed directly into tenured space)

I usually try an eden size of 4 - 24 GB but make sure tenured space is 0.5 to 2 GB in size.